# How to export the call tree to a text file from firefox profiler

Tags: firefox, profiler

I have a firefox profile and I would like to dump the calling context tree in a text file. Is there any tool to do so?

Comment: There's a "Save" link to save to JSON. Or do you need a file of a particular format?

Comment: I only need each trace as the caller ->callee format. Such that Trace 1: A->B->C, Trace2: D->E->A

Comment: I don't understand your description... It appears that in Firefox 46 you were supposed to be able to do a CTRL+A, CTRL+C to copy the contents of the "Call Tree" tab to the clipboard (and later save to text), but it doesn't work for me in the current nightly.

Comment: Forgot to link to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1081245 where I found out about the CTRL+A/C trick. I got a notification about a new comment here, but you seem to have deleted it afterwards?..